# Which View Controller is instantiating the Destination View Controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, selector

So here is what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a common `MapViewController` and two other view controllers that I want to send data from. `ExploreViewController` and `SavedPlacesViewController`.

I'm not using segues to do this. Instead I'm using something like this:

```
[mapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showExploreMap:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and then declaring the `showExploreMap` method to push the `MapViewController` to the `navigationController`.

I've done this for `ExploreViewController` and it works perfectly but I can't figure out how I can do this for `SavedPlacesViewController` since the data is coming from a different model.

I think somehow I need to figure out which `ViewController` is calling `MapViewController` so I can figure out which data model to use.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synthesize an NSString in MapViewController.

MapViewController.h:-

```
NSString  *fromClass;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *fromClass;
```

MapViewController.m:-

```
@synthesize fromClass;
```

ExploreViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)showExploreMap:(id)sender{
    MapViewController *obj=[[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController Bundle:nil];
    obj.fromClass=[NSString stringWithString:@"ExploreViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```

SavedPlacesViewController.m

```
MapViewController *obj=[[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController Bundle:nil];
obj.fromClass=[NSString stringWithString:@"SavedPlacesViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

MapViewController.m

```
if([fromClass isEqualToString @"ExploreViewController"])
{
    //use datasource for ExploreViewController
}
else
{
    //use datasource for SavedPlacesViewController
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot Pratyusha. You saved me a ton of time!